# Passing variables in a class

Tags: javascript, css, variables

I have a class 'container' with an id.

```
<div class="container" id="1500"></div>
```

Now in my javascript I fetch the id with the following code:

```
$('.container:' + place).click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Is there a possible way to link also a title in the class 'container'?
If I debug my code and set a watch point on the attribute $(this), there is a field 'innerText' and field 'OuterText' with the value I want, but I can't fetch it.

Is there a possible way to get these attributes or can I pass a variable by initializing the container?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by _Is there a possible way to link also a title in the class 'container'?_. Would you mind explaining that part again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using jQuery you can access them using `$(this)[0].innerText` and `$(this)[0].outerText`

Are you sure its a good idea to have an ID that starts with an integer and not a letter?

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if you can vincule that, maybe you can work with id only, and you can call via jquery for example if you have `<div  id="container1500"></div>` yu can call `var val=$("#container1500").html();` [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/fw0eoex7/)

now if you have a dinamic var, you can use `var val=$("#container" + i).html();` where "i" is a dinamic var, for example in `for(var i =0 ;....`